# Significant t-test but distribution plots overlaps

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, python, t-test, paired-data

I have run a paired samples t-test of before and after observations in python using scipy stats ttest_rel, which came out p= 0.006, so highly significant, suggesting that the participants had different results after the treatment. However, the distribution plots and boxplots are coming out overlapping. Perhaps this could be because the sample size is quite large (4100 participants). Should I run a Cohen's effect size test, or should I run a completely different test, or is it really significant at all?

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image]

Comment: [scipy.stats.ttest_rel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) performs the paired t-test. So it's more informative to plot one histogram of the paired differences (and center it at 0).

Comment: A t test does not assess distributional overlap, nor does it even involve any measure of overlap in its calculation.  The first thing to establish, then, is *what are you even trying to test?*

Comment: @user370970 It looks like the blue has considerably greater area than the orange; if the blue part really represents a density (i.e. with area 1) ... where's the rest of the orange density?